# structuremap nancy bootstrapper

Tags: structuremap, nancy

I am trying to boot strap nancyfx with structuremap bootstrapper 
https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Bootstrappers.StructureMap

Here is my setup:

```
        protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(IContainer container)
    {

        container.Configure(x =>
        {
            x.ForSingletonOf<IRazorConfiguration>()
                .Use<DefaultRazorConfiguration>();

           x.ForSingletonOf<ISessionContainer>().Use<SessionContainer>();

           x.For<IRepository>().LifecycleIs(new HttpContextLifecycle()).Use<Repository>();

            x.Scan(scanner=>
            {
                scanner.TheCallingAssembly();
                scanner.AddAllTypesOf<IRepository>();

            });
        });
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
    }

 public interface IRepository
{
   void Save();
}

   public class Repository:IRepository
{

   ISessionContainer _session;
   public Repository(ISessionContainer container)
   {
       _session = container;
   }

   public void Save()
   {

   }
}
```

When I use `var repo = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository>();`, I get this exception:

```
StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily Infrastructure.IRepository, Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Comment: Where are you trying to get the reference to `IRepository`? Using ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>() is rarely necessary with NancyFX. Would you update with a sample of the code/call stack where you are using `IRepository`? (Starting with the NancyModule, if you can)

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to help you get rid of the hack... the source of your problem is the way you are using ObjectFactory. Really you shouldn't be using ObjectFactory to "GetInstance" inside your NancyModule. Instead, you should include IRepository in the constructor of the NancyModule where the repository is needed. Then, Structuremap (which has been wired into the Nancy framework using your bootstrapper) will simple inject the concrete repository into your module when it is instantiated. Here's an example of a NancyModule:

```
public class ProductModule : NancyModule {

    private IRepository _repository;

    public ProductModule(IRepository repository) {

        _repository = repository;

        SetupRoutes();
    }

    private void SetupRoutes() {
        Get["/product/{id}"] = p => {
            return _repository.Get<Product>((int)p.id);
        };        
    }
}
```

Here, the module isn't calling out to the IOC to get a repo... it's already got it. Your bootstrapper makes this possible. Now, you can get rid of the hacky configuration of ObjectFactory.

As some general advice, if you find yourself using "ObjectFactory" to resolve types, you should slap yourself and stop typing. Instead, you should inject the dependency using constructor injection like I show above.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what happened to the proposed answer, but here is how I ended up resolving this issue.

```
protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(IContainer container)
{
    container.Configure(x =>
    {
        x.ForSingletonOf<IRazorConfiguration>()
            .Use<DefaultRazorConfiguration>();
        x.ForSingletonOf<ISessionContainer>().Use<SessionContainer>();//Duplicate
        x.Scan(scanner=>
        {
            scanner.TheCallingAssembly();
            scanner.AddAllTypesOf<IRepository>();
        });
    });
    ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
    {
        x.ForSingletonOf<ISessionContainer>().Use<SessionContainer>();//Duplicate
        x.For<IRepository>().Use<Repository>();
    });
    base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
}
```

It's a hack but this is the only way I managed to get this to work.